# C# Поиск строк в текстовом файле по ключевому слову

Tags: c#

Всем привет. У меня есть текстовый файл, в котором написано id города и сам город через запятую.
Пример:

1241,Moscow

1232,Sankt-Peterburg

1421,Ekateriburg

1314,Prosekatir

1412,Alexandria
...

Мне нужно с помощью ключевого слова (Например, ekat) найти все строки, которые имеют это ключевое слово. И получить:

```
1421,Ekateriburg
1314,Prosekatir
```

Пытался сделать это с помощью такого кода:

```
string keyWord = countryTextBox.Text;
string str = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/city.txt");
var kek = str.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '.', ',', ':'}).ToList();
foreach (string s in kek)
   {
       if (s.Trim() != "" && Regex.IsMatch(s, keyWord))
       {
             MessageBox.Show(kek[kek.IndexOf(keyWord) + 1] + " " + kek[kek.IndexOf(keyWord) + 3], "Найденные ID по ключевому слову", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
             break;
       }
    }
```

Но он выводит только часть и не совсем правильную:

```
Ekateriburg
1314,Prosekatir
1412
```

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо. Взял несколько частей из кода каждого, кто помог в комментариях, и вставил в свою программу. Ещё раз, спасибо :)

Comment: Это были не комментарии, а ответы. Если вы хотите отблагодарить отвечающего, то следует оценить его ответ нажав на стрелку вверх. Если вас какой-то из ответов полностью устраивает, то отметьте этот ответ галкой.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(Application.StartupPath + "/city.txt");
string result = string.Join("\n",
    lines.Where(s => s.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0));
MessageBox.Show(result, "Найденные ID по ключевому слову");
```

Answer (score 1):

Неплохой вопрос для практики алгоритмов.

Там понадобится простая структура данных - Trie. Это по сути обычное дерево, где связи между узлами представлены символами.

```
class TrieNode
{
    private HashSet<int> _cities = new HashSet<int>();
    private Dictionary<char, TrieNode> _children = new Dictionary<char, TrieNode>();

    public void Add(int id, string city, int index = 0)
    {
        if (index >= city.Length) return;
        _cities.Add(id);
        var c = city[index];

        if (!_children.ContainsKey(c)) _children[c] = new TrieNode();
        TrieNode child = _children[c];
        child.Add(id, city, index+1);       
    }

    public IEnumerable<int> GetCities(string prefix, int index = 0)
    {       
        if (index == prefix.Length) return _cities;     
        if (_children.ContainsKey(prefix[index])) 
             return _children[prefix[index]].GetCities(prefix, index+1);
        return Enumerable.Empty<int>();     
    }
}
```

Теперь можно считать все города из файла

```
var fname = @"D:\temp\SO\1099753\sample.txt";
var citiesById = File.ReadAllLines(fname)
        .Select(x => x.Split(','))
        .Select(x => (int.Parse(x[0]), x[1]))
        .ToDictionary(x=>x.Item1, x=>x.Item2);
```

После создадим корневой узел и закинем туда все города, включая все постфиксы городов

```
var root = new TrieNode();  
foreach(var cityWithId in citiesById)   
    for(int i=0; i<cityWithId.Value.Length; i++)
        root.Add(cityWithId.Key, cityWithId.Value.ToLowerInvariant(), i);
```

Поиск становится шустрым и несложным делом

```
Console.WriteLine("ekat cities:");
foreach (var cityId in root.GetCities("ekat"))
    Console.WriteLine(citiesById[cityId]);

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("os cities:");
foreach (var cityId in root.GetCities("os"))
    Console.WriteLine(citiesById[cityId]);
```

Вывод

```
ekat cities:
Ekateriburg
Prosekatir

os cities:
Moscow
Prosekatir
```

Answer (score 0):

Для удобства создайте класс, который будет содержать в себе ID и название:

```
class City
{
    public City(int id, string name)
        => (Id, Name) = (id, name);

    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}
```

Далее прочитайте все построчно из файла и заполните список:

```
var list = File.ReadAllLines("Test.txt").Select(x => x.Split(',')).Select(x => new City(int.Parse(x[0]), x[1]));
```

Ну а дальше делайте поиск чего вам надо:

```
var result = list.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("ekat"));
```

В результате вы получите один объект: `1314,Prosekatir`. Если надо еще захватить и `Ekateriburg`, то приводите все в нижний регистр (`Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains("ekat"))`).